# Angular 10 fails to map object from request to interface correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular10

When getting an object wrapped in a Result class I made, the controller and browser dev tools show the response is correct, however when I console log it from the subscription one of the nested values is undefined while the rest of the object is in tact. I've checked the interface for differences, there are none. Been stuck on this for a bit any help is much appreciated.

From Console.log
[image]

From Controller
[image]

Result class

[image]

Method calling service

[image]

service

[image]

Comment: brother the screenshot doesn't show the same data!! you are comparing to different lines (serviceType = EOM in the first screenshot while it's MOSQA in the second!)
in either way make sure you are calling the same endpoint in with the same parameters in both postman and from your app

Comment: It is the same data. There are 2 services. One mosquito (mosqa) and one every other month (eom). postman and the console just ordered them differently. I will update the post.

Comment: your response is modified somewhere! check your interceptors if you have any

Comment: Is your interface using an Array for linesOfSalesCommissions? If you didn't make that an array it'll expect a single object yet receives an array, which makes it undefined...

Comment: Thank you all for the input. as for the implementation of the interface, yes it is set up for a list. It had been working for over a year which is why I was at my whit's end. The problem  was resolved by pulling a fresh instance of my branch down. Something must have been corrupted along the way. I appreciate the input